# Git command: get history of executed command in branches of all users

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

As a profile maintainer on a GitLab repository, i'm looking for a method to get all the executed commands in one branch per user.

Is there a predefined method on GitLab to retrieve all the commanders ?

Thank you.

Comment: I think there's a human-language-translation issue here (I have no idea what "exciter commands" means for instance) but I will note that you asked about Git*Hub* in the text, then used the Git*Lab*-ci *tag*. GitHub and GitLab are very different (and neither one is Git) so either your text is wrong or your tags are wrong (or perhaps both!).

Comment: i means executed, i thnink that we cant see the executed commands of the other users of git, so i wonder if there is a method in Gitlab to get the history executed commands by user. thanks

Comment: Git is also *distributed*. If you have a centralized repository on a self-hosted GitLab system, and I clone your centralized repository, my clone is *mine*. You cannot see what I do with it after that. All you *can* know is that I contacted your GitLab server and cloned the repository. If I then send new commits to your GitLab server, once again, all you can know is that I sent new commits to your server: you cannot tell how I produced these commits. This all assumes you're using Git*Lab* (not Git*Hub*) and have your own server.